# Deleting in a heap, why does this implementation switch the values of the last element, not just replace it?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, pseudocode, performance

(USC CSCI 303 Homework 4) Problem 7 (6.5-7):

> The operation `Heap-Delete(A, i)` deletes the item in node `i` from heap `A`. Give an implementation of `Heap-Delete` that runs in *O*(*lg n*) time for an *n*-element max-heap.

here's the pseudo-code and description of the reference solution:

```
Heap-Delete(A, i)
    A[i] ↔ A[length(A)] 
    length(A) ← length(A) - 1
    Heapify(A, i)
```

> The algorithm deletes the element at node `i`, and replaces it with the last element.  Then the algorithm runs `Heapify` from the node `i`.

isn't it better if "↔" was "←" instead? **or** is this really necessary?

I got this from
http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci303/cs303hw4solutions.pdf (Page 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is done so that `Heap-Delete()` can be called repeatedly during execution of a heapsort. In heapsort, the largest item is taken off the heap, stashed in the last item of the heap, and the heap size is decreased by one. Then the heap is re-heapified, and you proceed to the next largest item. The end result, when the heap is size 1, is that the array on which the heap is/was based is sorted from smallest to largest.  Writing `Heap-Delete()` in this way allows `Heap-Sort()` to be very simple:

```
while (HeapSize>0)
   HeapDelete(0)
```

Now it doesn't look like your `Heap-Delete()` keeps track of heap size outside of `length`, which might be evidence against my theory. But this is my best guess anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really necessary. Perhaps the intent is to return that element, in which case you need to store it *somewhere*, before being overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

Here only pointer to the root node is given so if you want to delete the last node also (for those who says it takes o(1) to delete a leaf node)

You have to traverse log(n) to reach to the leaf then only answer is b.